# Sails.js - How to avoid Sails JS find Id on database table (because the table does not have id column)

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, postgresql, sails.js

I'm new in Sails JS (Node JS based). I get error :

> [Error (E_UNKNOWN) Encountered an unexpected error] Details:  error:
>   column MyTable.id does not exist

The error comes when i execute this syntax :

```
MyTable.find().then(function (locations) { .. }.catch(function (err) { .. }
```

The error show my table doesn't have id column. My table doesn't have id column and i don't want to add "id" column (because this database is exist database before i use sails to create API for this Database).

MyTable's column are :

1. name
2. address
3. ID_number

How to avoid Sails JS + Waterline to search "id" column ?

Comment: Can you add the code in your model?

Comment: @Zakir any solution you found for this query?

Answer (score 2):

```
module.exports = {
    autoCreatedAt:false,
    autoUpdatedAt:false,
    id:false,
    tableName: 'jobs_cats',
    attributes: {
            pc_id: {
                type: 'integer', 
                primaryKey: true,
                autoIncrement: true
            },
        project_id: 'integer',
        cat_id: 'integer'
        }
```

Comment: Can you add more explanations ?